# CKEditor 4 Toolbar Definitions

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have CKEditor 4, and want to configure a set of toolbars inline with this documentation for CKEditor 3: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar.

Basically I want to setup a few Toolbar definitions (e.g. config.toolbar_Email with one toolbar configuration, and config.toolbar_Cmscontent with another set).

Then when I declare CKEditor on an element, I can specify which toolbar I wanto to use.. eg:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    toolbar : 'Email'
});
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    toolbar : 'Cmscontent'
});
```

I can't get this working in CKEditor4, and can't find anything on it other than in CKEditor 3 documentation.

Can anyone tell me if this has been deprecated in v4?  Is there another way I can setup my own toolbar definitions?

Many Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is still available in CKEditor 4.x:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_MyCustomToolbar = [ [ 'Bold' ] ];
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_MyYetAnotherCustomToolbar = [ [ 'Italic' ] ];

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    toolbar: 'MyCustomToolbar'
} );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
    toolbar: 'MyYetAnotherCustomToolbar'
} );
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/CHKqy/). Read [some docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar). Follow [the guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar).

Comment: Thanks Oleq..  I was trying to define my custom toolbars in config.js, but just couldn't get them working.. have not just set them in a custom file and working fine.  thanks!!